# maxDate option in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Jquery UI datepicker like this.

[image]
I can only select month and year from the datepicker.
code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     dateFormat: 'M yy',
     maxDate: '0',                      
     onClose: function() {
          var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
          var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));                              
    },
     beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('calendar-off');                             
     }
});
```

If I set  `maxDate: '0'` the maximum month and year I can select is the current month and current year.
I want to set the maximum month and year using jquery.
For a normal datepicker with date,month,year, first I remove this `maxDate: '0'`code and  I used the following code to set the maximum date

```
var maximumDate = '07-15-2013';
$("#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maximumDate);
```

How can i set the maximum date in month and year picker?
The above code is not working in this case.Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: maxDate string must be in the format defined by the dateFormat option. Check your dateFormat option or use date object instead: `var maximumDate = new Date(2013,7,15);`.

Comment: @pipo("#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate","7/15/2013"); this code works fine for normal datepicker.But not in month and year picker.

Comment: @pipo I tried a lot as you told,Finally I found the answer.Thanks pipo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tried the following code.It works fine for me.

```
    var date = new Date("2013-07-15");
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate));
```

Example fiddle I created:[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLjDH/38/)

Answer (score 4):

Try This to choose **max/min dates** from month and year datepicker.

See this fiddle for the full solution: [Month/Year Picker @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTpUY/5/)

```
var searchMinDate = "-2y";
var searchMaxDate = "-1m";
if ((new Date()).getDate() <= 5) {
    searchMaxDate = "-2m";
}
$("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "M yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showAnim: "",
    minDate: searchMinDate,
    maxDate: searchMaxDate,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        if ((datestr = $("#txtFrom").val()).length > 0) {
            var year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
            var month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), "#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
        $("#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        },
        onClose: function (input, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            var to = $("#txtTo").val();
            $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            if (to.length > 0) {
                var toyear = to.substring(to.length - 4, to.length);
                var tomonth = jQuery.inArray(to.substring(0, to.length - 5), $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
                $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(toyear, tomonth, 1));
                $("#txtTo").datepicker('setDate', new Date(toyear, tomonth, 1));
            }
        }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "M yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showAnim: "",
        minDate: searchMinDate,
        maxDate: searchMaxDate,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            if ((datestr = $("#txtTo").val()).length > 0) {
                var year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                var month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
                $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#txtTo").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        },
        onClose: function (input, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $("#txtTo").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $("#txtTo").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            var from = $("#txtFrom").val();
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            if (from.length > 0) {
                var fryear = from.substring(from.length - 4, from.length);
                var frmonth = jQuery.inArray(from.substring(0, from.length - 5), $("#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort'));
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(fryear, frmonth, 1));
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker('setDate', new Date(fryear, frmonth, 1));
            }

        }
    });
```

Also add this to a style block as mentioned above:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none !important; }
```